# Select only rows mith minimum cost

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

I need to pull back a set of data for a view where only rows with the the minimum cost are returned. I am joining 3 tables and they are big tables (225 million records a piece give or take) so performance is essential.

```
SELECT  RIC.CarrierName, L.LoadGuid, RIC.RateIQCarrierid, RIRD.Cost
FROM tblLoads L 
INNER JOIN RateIQRecord RIR ON L.LoadGuid = RIR.LoadGuId 
INNER JOIN RateIQCarrier RIC ON RIR.RateIQRecordID = RIC.RateIQRecordID
INNER JOIN RateIQRateDetail RIRD ON RIC.RateIQRecordID = RIRD.RateIQRecordID
AND CAST(L.CreatedDate AS Datetime)  Between '03/3/2014' and '03/3/2014 23:59:59.997'
```

Here is an example of the data set based of the code above

```
CarrierName        LoadGuid                     Carrierid   Cost
Carrier a          FF98010A-90CE-4541-AB88-683645352712 210677951   192.51
Carrier a          FF98010A-90CE-4541-AB88-683645352712 210677921   153.17
Carrier b          FF98010A-90CE-4541-AB88-683645352712 210677925   196.28
Carrier b          FF98010A-90CE-4541-AB88-683645352712 210677947   280.65
Carrier b          FF98010A-90CE-4541-AB88-683645352712 210677949   241.71
```

Here is what I need:

```
CarrierName        LoadGuid                         Carrierid   Cost
Carrier a          FF98010A-90CE-4541-AB88-683645352712 210677921     153.17
Carrier b          FF98010A-90CE-4541-AB88-683645352712 210677925     196.28
```

Comment: What is the datatype of tblLoads.CreatedDate?

Comment: @abatishchev, It is Datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:
Note:I'm assuming you have SQL Server 2008 or above. ROW_NUMBER() won;t work otherwise.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT  RIC.CarrierName,
            L.LoadGuid,
            RIC.RateIQCarrierid,
            RIRD.Cost,
            --Partition says look at each carrier as a group, then number them in order of cost lowest to highest.
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RIC.CarrierName ORDER BY Cost) rank_num
    FROM tblLoads L 
    INNER JOIN  RateIQRecord RIR 
                ON L.LoadGuid = RIR.LoadGuId 
    INNER JOIN  RateIQCarrier RIC 
                ON RIR.RateIQRecordID = RIC.RateIQRecordID
    INNER JOIN  RateIQRateDetail RIRD 
                ON RIC.RateIQRecordID = RIRD.RateIQRecordID

                --Don't do it this way
                --AND CAST(L.CreatedDate AS Datetime)  Between '03/3/2014' and '03/3/2014 23:59:59.997'

                --Try this instead
                AND CAST(L.CreatedDate AS DATE) = '03/03/2014'
) A
--Only grab the lowest number aka first of row number
WHERE A.rank_num = 1
```

Comment: Yes Perfect! Thanks for the tip on the date constraint as well.